# what are the prerequisite for ROS?

Tags: ros, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have recently completed my Bachelors in Computer science  , i have no such  exposure to **ROS** or any thing related to it

now i have been offered **Internship** in development in **ROS**  should i go for it ?

My question is  what are the mandatory prerequisite for ROS ?
and
How much time it would take me to learn ROS  ?

please also refer any guidance regarding ROS to learn it and get some overview of it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202533/what-are-the-prerequisite-for-ros-?/) by [Hassaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21573/hassaan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A prerequisite for ROS is the willingness to learn, a computer, and some time (6 months).

You'll want to start here:
http://www.ros.org/install/

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2015-02-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-02-05**:
I've always found the Conceptual Overview to be informative: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Introduction

**Comment by [Hassaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21573/hassaan/) on 2015-02-06**:
first thanks for your reply.
Second ill be given  3 months of internship  , within  that 2 weeks would be given for training and self learning and after that ill be given small assignments ?

so would it will be achievable for any person very new to ROS ?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-03-22**:
It's hard to answer. Everyone learns different things at different rates. You should be able to get talker listener working just following the tutorials in an hour or two. From there you can effectively use it but you won't be an expert until you've used it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This video will help you get a good overview of ROS. Best of luck :). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfefT2jsDzU

---

Originally posted by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) with karma: 63 on 2015-02-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hassaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21573/hassaan/) on 2015-02-06**:
Thanks for the video
but i would be very glad if let me know how much time it would require me to get into ROS From scratch ?